# What happens when a three phase motor designed for delta connection is run star-connected?

Tags: induction-motor, electromagnetic

What happens when a three phase motor designed for delta connection is run star-connected?

Comment: is this a schoolwork question?

Answer (score 3):

For a designed-for-delta three-phase motor, its phase voltage is equal to the line voltage.

For a designed-for-delta three-phase motor that is run star-connected, its phase voltage is lowered to 1 / √3 of line voltage and its torque to 1 / 3  of rated torque.

At no-load or reduced load, the motor will run at its rated speed without any problem.

However, at rated load, current drawn by the motor will exceed its rated current causing it to overheat and ultimately get burnt.